# Generar una tabla que almacene configuraciones de mi sitio web, ¿es una buena práctica en el diseño de una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, web

Estoy generando una página web en donde después de haber transcurrido 1 semana, los registros de ciertas tablas en mi base de datos deberían borrarse.

Mi pregunta es que si ¿se considera buena práctica en el diseño de base de datos el generar una tabla que guarde información de configuración de mi sitio web?, algo como: **"ultimo_dia_de_la_semana_actual"**, para que posteriormente en el cliente de mi apliación pueda verificar ese dato y realizar la acción correspondiente de borrado

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Recomienden cómo hacer..." no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre opinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La respuesta depende de cómo se diseñe e implemente lo que comentas. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por si la pregunta termina cerrada te diré que todo en la Base se modifica mucho mas rápido que en código. En lo personal cuando hago un proyecto siempre tengo una tabla **config** y una tabla **assets**, esta ultima para recursos menos críticos...

Comment: Es basado en opiniones, pero personalmente pienso que no es mala practica tener una tabla config en vez de un archivo físico.

Comment: Guardar configuraciones de usuario en BDD puede ser un problema bajo ciertas condiciones, mucho depende de la frecuencia de cambio, y la frecuencia de lectura; algo que normalmente saltaría durante las pruebas de estrés.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo general lo que deseas hacer es guardar las fechas de las modificaciones. Lo que se suele hacer es tener en la misma tabla una columna 'ultima_modificacion_[modificacion]' Y así con cada columna que debería eliminarse el dato mismo.
Allí ir pisando los datos anteriores o si tienes que ir creando nuevas filas asegurate de seleccionar bien el Order By, así ir viendo siempre el último dato creado.
Desde mi experiencia te puedo decir que de está forma te ayudara en crear consultas en un futuro